# Nonlinear first-stage specification in 2SLS

Tags: nonlinear-regression, 2sls

My question is **whether there are any substantial benefits** from specifying a nonlinear first-stage in 2SLS regression. Generally, we assume that first stage is a linear relationship, like:

\begin{align}
y_1 &= X\beta + \gamma y_2 + \varepsilon  \\
y_2 &= Z\theta + \nu
\end{align}

where $y_2$ is an endogeneous variable. But in certain case, a nonlinear relationship would be a better specification for DGP. For example, if we imagine $y_2$ is the duration time (in years) for a immigrant staying in a city, there is obviously a sample selection problem: $y_2$ is $0$ for original city residents or other residents choose not to migrate, and a positive integer for those who decide to migrate. In this case, it's better to specification a count data model like:

$$
y_2 = {\rm Poisson}(Z\theta + \nu)
$$

However, given that we are not interested in $y_2$, but in $y_1$, would that really make a big difference between two specifications? Consider that, to implement the second specification, we have to do some MLE programming rather than using built-in commands in a standard package like Stata.

Comment: There could be two concerns for using nonlinear 1st step specification. One is about consistency, and the other is about efficiency. If the true DGP governing the relationship between the endogenous variable and the IV is nonlinear, and one keeps using linear specification, it is possible the first stage regression itself suffers from endogeneity problem as $E(\nu \vert Z) = E(Y \vert Z) - Z \theta$ could differ from $0$ when $E(Y\vert Z$ is nonlinear in $Z$. Consequently, the second stage estimation would be inconsistent.

Comment: The efficiency concern can be understood by observing the variance formula of the 2SLS estimators. Roughly speaking, the variance is negatively proportional to length of the projection of the endogenous variable $Y_2$ on the space of the IV $Z$. When the nonlinear specification is more "close" to the true DGP than the linear specification, the projection of $Y_2$ on $Z$ will have longer length, henceforth the resulted 2SLS has smaller variance.

Comment: A slight different answer from the statalist http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1303148-weak-iv-test-in-2sls-when-first-stage-is-nonlinear